# Getting the reference of a template iterator reference

Tags: c++, iterator

I need to get a reference to an iterator of a reference. However, my compiler is choking on this code:

```
template <typename InputIterator> size_t iLongestBegin(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference SequenceT;
        //Problem is next line
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename SequenceT::iterator>::reference T;
    for(size_t idx; idx < first->length(); idx++)
    {
        T curChar = (*first)[idx];
        for (InputIterator cur = first; cur != last; cur++)
        {
            if (cur->length() < idx)
                return idx;
            if (_tolower(cur->at(idx)) != _tolower(curChar))
                return idx;
        }
    }
    return first->length();
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? The error is

```
error C2825: 'SequenceT': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, just solved it :)

Problem is that SequenceT is a reference, not a type. Since you can't generally take the address of a reference type, the compiler won't generate iterators for it. I need to use value_type instead of reference:

```
template <typename InputIterator> size_t iLongestBegin(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference SequenceT;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type::iterator>::reference T;
    for(size_t idx; idx < first->length(); idx++)
    {
        typename T curChar = (*first)[idx];
        for (InputIterator cur = first; cur != last; cur++)
        {
            if (cur->length() < idx)
                return idx;
            if (_tolower(cur->at(idx)) != _tolower(curChar))
                return idx;
        }
    }
    return first->length();
}
```

Comment: You still have some things wrong. "typename T" should be just "T", and there is "typename" needed before "std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type::iterator" . Looks like you compile with some too lax compiler. Later if you want to compile with another one, you will get many problems

Comment: Doesn't really bother me for now. Only compiler this thing will ever be pointed at is msvc++. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss specifying `SequenceT` in the template argument list - Where is it defined? Or maybe you must indicate that it's a type with `typename SequenceT`.

Comment: It's a typedef on the line prior to the one he flagged as an error.

Comment: The function is passed a std::list<std::basic_string<wchar_t> > .

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `typename SequenceT::iterator` instead of just `SequenceT::iterator`. This is because `SequenceT` is a type that is derived from your template parameters (a "dependent type", in standard lingo), and `iterator` is a nested type in `SequenceT`, not a function or variable. When both of these things are true, the compiler can't figure out what you mean and needs to be told that `SequenceT::iterator` is a type with `typename`.

Comment: Changed it to "typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename SequenceT::iterator>::reference T;" Still no joy

Comment: SequenceT is a reference to an element in the iterator sequence, so it doesn't have any nested typedefs. For example, if InputIterator is a vector<string>::iterator, then SequenceT is a "string &". Can you clarify what you want T to be in this case?

Comment: T should be wchar_t given that the iterators are pointing to a std::list<std::basic_string<wchar_t> >

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles with g++ 4.4.0:

```
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template <typename InputIterator> size_t iLongestBegin(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference SequenceT;
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<typename SequenceT::iterator>::reference T;
   for(size_t idx; idx < first->length(); idx++)
   {
      T curChar = (*first)[idx];
      for (InputIterator cur = first; cur != last; cur++)
      {
         if (cur->length() < idx)
             return idx;
         if (_tolower(cur->at(idx)) != _tolower(curChar))
             return idx;
      }
   }
    return first->length();
}
```

Comment: Mine compiles fine too until I call it. Did you throw test data at it?

Comment: No. If you have problems with code that is only demonstrable with certain test data, please include the test code in your question.

Comment: The problem code is there. My compiler doesn't even attempt to resolve the types and compile any template functions unless they are called. Not sure if GCC behaves that way.

Comment: A C++ compiler must process the template, whether it is used or not.